# Block access to a redirected subdomain on an IP basis

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a subdomain (`mail.mywebsite.com`) that points to the login page that I've set up for Google apps (per [their instructions](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53340)). I'm currently using a CNAME record to point users to the page.

However, I'd like to restrict access to this subdomain on an IP basis (effectively create a whitelist).

Not sure if modifiying .htaccess on my server is an option, as the domain is configured in the registrar to forward to Google, not content on my server.

Any suggestions for how I could accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you've done this using a DNS CNAME, you have no control over who can access `mail.mywebsite.com` since it's not even your server that's accepting requests (it's Google's server).

Unless there's some way to setup access restrictions on Google, there's not going to be anything that you can do.

Alternatively, you can change the CNAME to point to your server, then use a reverse proxy to proxy the requests to Google. You can then use access controls to setup what IPs will be proxied and all the rest will just get 403'ed. Can't setup `ProxyPass` in htaccess file though, need to do it in server/vhost config, but you *can* use the `P` flag in mod_rewrite to reverse proxy for you.